# Is chicken generally kosher?

Tags: food

Is chicken generally kosher at the average grocery store? I don’t eat beef much but enjoy chicken a lot and wonder if it’s generally kosher

Comment: No. Chicken has to be specially processed to be Kosher (hand slaughtered by an expert, salted to remove the blood, and more). Only specially certified chicken will be Kosher, and it will be way more expensive.

Comment: Species is kosher, but as Yishai noted, only if *very* specially processed.

Comment: The salmon or steelhead trout, on the other hand, is probably fine as-is.

Comment: @Yishai why don't you put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I am known as being somewhat "liberal" with Kashrut laws. But there is no gray area here. Unless the chicken meat is specifically labeled as kosher, then it is not kosher.

You would have better luck with turkey. Since Israel and other middle eastern countries eat a lot of turkey, a lot of turkey slaughterhouses make all their turkey's kosher and halal. They often don't advertise it as such because Americans go on insanity tirades where they make claims the [turkeys are being sacrificed to Allah](https://www.theatlantic.com/national/archive/2011/11/every-single-butterball-turkey-has-been-sacrificed-to-allah/249063/). But either way, in my experience you are more likely to find a whole turkey for sale in an American supermarket that's marked as kosher than you are to find chickens. But at the end of the day, the Turkey needs to be certified as kosher on the labeling of the product, or you must call the company to confirm its status. One should not assume it's kosher. The only foods we are allowed to assume are kosher are vegetables, plants, and fruits.

Comment: Maybe in Israel you could find the turkey kosher ... but in America? Unless it's specifically a kosher brand, I highly doubt it. (Empire brand yes, Butterball brand no.)

Comment: See @yishai comment above

Comment: Halal isn't kosher. Any evidence they do this with kosher slaughter? And do they salt the meat at all?

Comment: @DoubleAA Halal isn't kosher. But the point is that Turkey companies often make their Turkeys halal or kosher, don't necessarily label it as such in America and only reveal it's halal or Kosher status on labeling outside the US. They are incentivized to make the meat Kosher and not just Halal because a kosher slaughter is halal and can be sold anywhere in the middle east, and then also to be sold in Israel